# Converting MediumBlob data into an Bitmap Image using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, bitmap, emgucv

I am trying to convert my mediumblob data which is in MySQL to Bitmap image, but I cannot do it. I am getting an error which is

> Parameter is not valid.

This is my c# code:

```
 MySqlCommand select = new MySqlCommand("Select FaceName, FaceImage From TrainingSet1", conn);
                MySqlDataReader reader = select.ExecuteReader();



                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    labels.Add(reader["FaceName"].ToString());


                    byte[] buffer = (byte[])reader["FaceImage"];
                    MessageBox.Show("kw");

                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);

                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ms); //prb is here
                    MessageBox.Show("remy");
                    Image<Gray, byte> image = new Image<Gray, byte>(bmp);
                    trainingImages.Add(image);
                }

                reader.Close();
```

This is my image adding functionality into the database:

```
 private byte[] ConvertToDBFormat(IImage InputImage)
    {
        Bitmap BmpImage = new Bitmap(InputImage.Bitmap);
        MemoryStream MyStream = new MemoryStream();
        BmpImage.Save(MyStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] ImageAsBytes = MyStream.ToArray();
        return ImageAsBytes;
    }
```

Can someone help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
 ms.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

You're first initializing the memory stream with the buffer, and then promply overwriting it with the same data - setting the current position to the end of the stream. When the `Bitmap` class tries to read from it - it won't get anything.

Simply skip the `Write` call and the memory stream will supply the data from the byte array.

Also - I would suggest having a `using` block around the memory stream and reader. And, if that `Image<>` class of you doesn't keep a reference around to the `Bitmap`, you should dispose of it immediately.

Comment: I am still getting the same error even after commenting it out... this is my full [code](http://pastebin.com/Zf2fT46U)

Comment: What exactly do you have in that byte array? A full bmp/png/jpg or is it raw image data?

Comment: If it's just raw data without a header `Bitmap` will have no way of knowing what to do with it. Do you know the format and size?

Comment: Given just a raw array of bytes there's no way to know. You need the pixel format, bits per pixel, row stride and dimensions of the image to be able to proceed. If you can show the code that generates and saves the image we might be able to help.

Comment: well i have edited my question with the image insertion method btw the picture format is jpeg

Comment: Which means you actually do have a complete jpeg in the database. From what I can see that code should work (as long as you remove the `Write` call). If not, manually check that the stored data is retrieved correctly from the database, i.e. content and length.

Comment: Compare the data you write to the database with what you get back.